# Zend: How to use 'not equal to' in WHERE clause?

Tags: zend-framework, mysql, where-clause

I am using following zend code to select all data from a table where verified=1 and it is working for me.

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();
$select = $table->select();
$select->where('verified = 1');
$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

No I want to select all data from that table where verified is not equal to '1'. I have tried the following ways but it is not fetching data.

```
$select->where('verified != 1');
$select->where('verified <> 1');
$select->where('verified != ?', 1);
```

Data structure for 'verified' column:

```
Field: verified
type: varchar(45)
Collation: utf8_bin         
NULL: Yes   
Default: NULL
```

Any idea that how to use 'not equal to' operator in WHERE clause in Zend? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any data in your database where verified != 1?

Comment: Yes. There are many NULLs,0s and 1s in verified column.

Comment: Tested example added to ansver. and NULLs are special colums. they can be only checked by IS NULL / IS NOT NULL

Comment: Hi SM: If I am checking any value other than 1. I just want to know that is there 1 or any thing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL supports a custom operator `<=>` which returns true if the operands are equal or both null.  It returns false if they are different, or if one operand is null.

```
$select->where('verified <=> 1');
```

This operator is non-standard.  Standard SQL has syntax: `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` that works just like MySQL's `<=>`.

Answer (score 6):

```
$select->where('verified != ?', 1);
```

Real worls query example:

```
    $query = $this->getDb()->select();
    $query->from('title', array('title_id' => 'id', 'title', 'production_year', 'phonetic_code'))
            ->where('kind_id = 1')
            ->where('title = ?', trim($title))
            ->where('production_year != ?', '2009')
            ->limit(1)
            ;
```

Selects movies info from IMDB database. Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since your column is a varchar perhaps try `where verified != '1' or verified is null`

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the table structure for the table you are querying? Is the column verified an int or string? Also try printing the SQL statement that ZEND builds, see the echo line below.

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();
$select = $table->select();
$select->where('verified = 1');
echo sprintf("sql %s",$select);
$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: db structure is added in question for verified column.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$select->where('verified != ?', '1');
```

put quotation marks around the value. It is working for me.